# Sorting an Oracle table inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlplus

I have a stored procedure which I am running from a .sql file which takes in inputs from the users and runs the procedure. The procedure runs many queries and inserts a row of values into the table. In the .sql file I have I would like to order the table by a certain column after I finish running the queries. Currently I have:

```
DECLARE
 NAMEPARAM VARCHAR2(200);
 VERSIONPARAM VARCHAR2(200);
 STARTDATE DATE;
 ENDDATE DATE;

BEGIN
 NAMEPARAM := '&1';
 VERSIONPARAM := '&2';
 STARTDATE := '&3';
 ENDDATE := '&4';

 PROCEDURE(NAMEPARAM, VERSIONPARAM, STARTDATE, ENDDATE);
 COMMIT;

 Select * from TABLE_NAME
 ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME ASC;

 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,SQLERRM);
 END;
 /
```

However It throws the error:

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

I dont know why it needs an into clause. Help?

Edit: 
To clarify I don't want to see an output of a sorted table I would like the table itself to be updated and sorted by the column in ascending order.

Comment: What do you mean "sort an Oracle table"?  Tables are unordered sets of rows.  They do not have an order.  Query results can be ordered, which is determined by the `order by` clause.

Comment: @javakid1993, I suspect you are labouring under the misunderstanding that rows in an Oracle table have an intrinsic order. There is no such thing. Rows are only sorted at query time.

Comment: Well what I meant was to have a clause even when inserting the rows to insert in order. But I understand the fault in where I was coming from. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a `SELECT` statement in a PL/SQL block, you need to do something with the results.  If you're expecting exactly one row, you'd do a `SELECT INTO` a local variable.  Assuming that you are expecting multiple rows, you could write a `FOR` loop that iterates over the rows or you could `BULK COLLECT` the rows into a PL/SQL collection.  You could also open a `SYS_REFCURSOR` but since there is no way to return that from an anonymous PL/SQL block, that seems unlikely to be what you want.

My guess is that you want the `SELECT` statement to be outside the PL/SQL block and you want whatever tool you are using to execute the .sql script to run the PL/SQL block to populate the table and then run the `SELECT` statement, writing the results to whatever file/ console you are spooling output to.

Comment: I dont want it to output anywhere I want the table itself to be updated and sorted by that column. I don't necessarily even want to see the output.

Comment: @javakid1993, did you read the other comments?  Generally, there is no "sorting" of a table's rows in the database files.  The results of a query can be ordered.  There are Index Organized Tables, that are different from standard, heap managed tables, but I doubt that is what you are asking.

Comment: As Gordon and OldProgrammer noted - why do you want to "sort the table" without wanting to any sorted output? It'd help if you can think clearly of your end result and then work out solution.